# как переключить локаль из экшена?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

у меня есть экшен, который должен переключать локаль:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def lang_toggle
    if params[:locale] == 'ru'
      I18n.locale = :en
    else
      I18n.locale = :ru
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end   
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/lang_toggle'
end
```

в основном шаблоне есть ссылки для выбора языка:

```
<nav class="language_area col-xs-6">
  <%= link_to 'Рус',  pages_lang_toggle_path, class: 'pull-right active' %>
  <%= link_to 'Eng',  pages_lang_toggle_path, class: 'pull-right' %>
</nav>
```

после клика по любой кнопке происходит вызов `lang_toggle` и перенаправление `redirect_to :back`. проблема в том, что не срабатывает:

```
I18n.locale = :??
```

Answer (score 1):

`I18n.locale = :en` - устанавливает локаль на текущий цикл запрос-ответ.

Тут 2 выхода:

- локаль делать частью URL (сложно, но правильно)
- где то хранить выбранную локаль(сессия, БД), и перед выполнением экшена устанавливать её.

Answer (score 0):

Например в `application_controller` можно такое написать.

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
    I18n.locale = <взять значение оттуда, куда записали>
end
```

А в вашем экшне делать запись значения. В сессию или в базу, да.